# ¿Cómo eliminar de un diccionario listas con diccionarios vacíos? Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una data como esta en la cual tengo un diccionario con listas que tienen diccionarios:

```
bloqueAtributos = {
   "Articulos":[
      {
         "id":3042,
         "titulo":"Propuesta de Investigación Socioeducativa de la UTPL",
         "keywords":"",
         "link_articulo":""
      },
      {
         "id":3043,
         "titulo":"Prueba",
         "keywords":"pruebas",
         "link_articulo":""
      },
      {
         "id":3044,
         "titulo":"Prueba",
         "keywords":"pruebas",
         "link_articulo":""
      }
   ],
   "Libros":[
      
   ],
   "Proyectos":[
      {
         "codigo_proyecto":""
      },
      {
         "codigo_proyecto":""
      }
   ],
   "GradoAcademico":[
      
   ],
   "Capacitacion":[
      {},
      {} 
   ]
}
```

Y estoy tratando de borrar las listas vacías y listas con diccionarios vacíos, para lo cual hago esto:

```
bloquesInfoRestante = {k:v for k,v in bloqueAtributos.items() if v !=[] and v !=[{}]}
print(bloquesInfoRestante)
```

Con eso puedo eliminar las listas que se encuentran vacías. Pero no las listas que se encuentran con mas de un diccionario vació.

Con lo que tengo ahora me devuelve esto:

```
bloquesInfoRestante = {
   "Articulos":[
      {
         "id":3042,
         "titulo":"Propuesta de Investigación Socioeducativa de la UTPL",
         "keywords":"",
         "link_articulo":""
      },
      {
         "id":3043,
         "titulo":"Prueba",
         "keywords":"pruebas",
         "link_articulo":""
      },
      {
         "id":3044,
         "titulo":"Prueba",
         "keywords":"pruebas",
         "link_articulo":""
      }
   ],
   "Proyectos":[
      {
         "codigo_proyecto":""
      },
      {
         "codigo_proyecto":""
      }
   ],
   "Capacitacion":[
      {},
      {}
   ]
}
```

Como ven solo me elimina las listas vacías, pero no las listas con diccionarios vacíos. Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para eliminar también las listas con diccionarios vacíos. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes considerar filtrar la lista `v` con `[item for item in v if item != {}]`, así garantizamos que la lista `v` tenga al menos un diccionario no vacío.

```
bloquesInfoRestante = {k:v for k,v in bloqueAtributos.items() if [item for item in v if item != {}]}
```

Si hay diccionarios que tengan al menos un diccionario no vacío como `{'a': [{}, {'foo': 2}], 'b': [], 'c': [{}, {}]}`, `bloquesInfoRestante` sería `{'a': [{}, {'foo': 2}]}`